# Control the size of the content in a zenity window?

Tags: user-interface, zenity

I can control the size of a [zenity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenity) window with the `--width` and the `--height` arguments:

```
$ zenity --info --text="This is an information box." --width=600 --height=400
```

Is there a way to control the size of the content? For example, can I double the size of the font used to display the text?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Zenity allows some markup like <b>, <i> or <span>. In fact it's [Pango Markup](https://docs.gtk.org/Pango/pango_markup.html). So larger text can be achieved with a span that has a font or size attribute:

For example:

```
zenity --info --text '<span foreground="blue" font="32">Some\nbig text</span>\n\n<i>(it is also blue)</i>'
```

Note that **font="32"** is another way to write **size="32768"** since size is in 1024ths of a point. **font="32"** is a partial font description containing only a size. See the documentation page.

See also:

```
zenity --info --text 'Normal <big>Big <big>Bigger</big></big>'
```

To increase the font size without specifying an exact size.

Comment: That works for me, for title only. For a list, it fails for the parameter column `--column="<span font='24'>logmsg</span>"`, and, unfortunately, for the lines to list, too. Maybe this is only configurable over system wide settings?