# How does one format multiple lines of Zenity --list --text?

Tags: pango, zenity

Formatting with [Pango Markup](https://developer.gnome.org/pango/stable/PangoMarkupFormat.html) has been shown to work on one --info --text entry in this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20338724/1186814).

I would like to use a monospace font for a multiline list of block devices (avoiding multiple columns):

```
IFS=$'\n'    
zenity --height=480 --width=700 --list --hide-header --column=device --text="Select a partition:" $(lsblk -n -o NAME,RM,TYPE,TRAN,FSTYPE,LABEL,VENDOR,MODEL)
```

Answer (score 1):

This script adjusts the gnome.desktop.interface font-name for the Zenity dialog:

```
fn=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name)
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name 'Monospace Bold 11'
ifs=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'    
selected=$(zenity --height=480 --width=700 --list --hide-header --column=device --text="Select a partition:" $(lsblk -n -o NAME,RM,TYPE,TRAN,FSTYPE,LABEL,VENDOR,MODEL))
IFS="$ifs"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface font-name "$fn"
```